# C++: Can the destructor be the only virtual function in a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, virtual-destructor

I read that the destructor should be declared virtual only if there is virtual function in a class.
Is this a requirement or is it possible to do otherwise?

Comment: You can just have a virtual destructor, but it's kind of pointless if you don't have any other virtual functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver what if you had a base A, derived B, and an A* smart pointer that points to a B. Without the virtual destructor, the B-specific member variables wouldn't be destroyed right?

Comment: @JohnFilleau: You're correct, but in that case it would also be virtually impossible to call any other B methods, so it's kind of pointless.

Comment: @JohnFilleau What would you do with that base pointer?  There are no virtual functions.

Comment: Depending on whether one considers a pure virtual declaration (with no definition) to be a function or just a virtual slot for a function, you may consider that many abstract base classes ("interfaces") have a virtual destructor alone.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Polymorphic destruction is a useful form of polymorphism all by itself.  You could have objects used in the processing of some job, that register themselves with a job cleanup list so they are all automatically freed when the job is completed.  Other code accesses them through their derived list, only the cleanup list holds a base pointer.

Comment: So, it is not just "allowed" but also useful. Thank you @BenVoigt

Comment: @JohnFilleau — if the code deletes an object if a derived type through a pointer to a base type and the base type does not have a virtual destructor the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: @NathanOliver Imagine a base class operating on a raw pointer/reference to some resource and a derived [set of] class[es] which manage acquisition/release of said resource in a constructor and destructor, respectively. Now, say, if a derived class instance is passed as unique_ptr to base class somewhere, you won't be able to achieve correct resource release without a virtual destructor in the base, albeit zero other virtual methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have virtual destructors if you intend to use your class in a polymorphic setting. If you don't plan to use polymorphism and polymorphic destruction (destruction through a base class) then you don't need a virtual destructor.

Usually, we use classes in a polymorphic setting when there are virtual functions. Having no virtual functions would force to use casts when using the classes. At that point, I would recommend to simply use a variant, which don't require virtual destructors at all.

With all that said, if the only operation you want to expose polymorphically is destruction, it could still be useful in some cases.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume, I think for a generic scenario whatever you mentioned applies.
Just as a note for readers looking at this answer, also take a look at the comments provided by Ben Voigt.

Comment: @pasha thanks! I added a paragraph about destruction being the targeted operation.